# How do I implement the equivalent for-loop?

Tags: java, python, for-loop

In java, I can have the following loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<=c;i++){
    for(int j=i; j<=C;j++){
        ecc...
    }
}
```

How do I write the equivalent loop in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) + [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range)

In python you can get a *range* by invoking `range(begin, end)` — where `begin` denotes the start of the range, and `end` is the upper limit (not included in the resulting range). Mathematically speaking the result will be the set of numbers in the range `[begin, end)`.

In order to *port* your [java](/questions/tagged/java) code into python, you can easily create an outer range with the construct previously mentioned, and then have the inner range depend on the former.

```
for i in range (0, c+1):
  for j in range (i, C+1):
    ...
```

---

#### Using [`while`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)

You can of course also write the equivalent looping construct using `while`, even though this is not very *pythonic* — nor is it as clean.

```
i = 0
while i <= c:
  j = i
  while j <= C:
    ...
    j += 1
  i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this,

```
for i in range(1, c + 1):
    for j in range(i, C + 1):
        ecc...
```

Please go through a basic python tutorial. One is found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, c+1):
    for j in range (i, C+1):
        print j
```

Answer (score 1):

in python you can write for like

```
for (setelements) in (set):
```

so for what you want it will be like

```
for i in range(1, c+1 ):
      for j in range(i, c+1 ):
            ecc...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c= 10
for i in range(1,10,1):
   for j in range(1,10,1):
       pass
```

The range takes 3 parameters(start,stop,step)
start - from where to begin a for loop, when to stop the loop and how much to step

in the above code snippet the loop will begin at 1, stop at 10 and will step by 1 every time just like i++ in java